# Using more than one salt in securing passwords

Tags: security, cryptography, salt

If I use more than 1 salt string, for example 3 or 4, would my password be more secure?

Comment: Slightly, not really, maybe. It's about the way you implement salts, not much about the salts themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the number of salts that counts, but the cumulative size of them. If you have at least 128 bit of a randomly generated salt, you should be fine. You only need a salt of appropriate size, but that is not the whole story.

For example, if you're using PBKDF2, you should use a high number of iterations in order to make it really hard for password crackers to brute-force the password. Nowadays, 1,000,000 iterations seems reasonable or you can calibrate it, so that one password hash takes roughly a second. If you use scrypt you should adjust the cost factor in the same way.

*Do not hash passwords with a single invocation of a hash function like SHA-256.*

Comment: Salts don’t have to be random but globally unique. However, randomness is often the key to achieve a high probability of global uniqueness.